# OpenId support for Yii

Tags: openid, yii, lightopenid, openid-selector

I want to play with OpenID support in Yii.

After researching for possible plugins, I found these two. One for OpenidSelector and one for LightOpenId

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/simpleopenidselector/

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/loid

Are these the right extensions to use in Yii for OpenId support?  Anything else?
And I would like to get some guide line on what to do with these extensions if they are correct.

This is what I think I need to do beside installing them as per instructions on the page.

1. Create OpenIdUserIdentity extends CUserIdentity and put the authenticate() code there
2. Create a login page and put the simpleopenidselector code in a view.
3. Create a actionOpenIdLogin methon in siteController

then I am kind of lost as I don't understand the Usage sample in Loid and I am not sure how to do (1) and (3) above.

Please let me know if I am on the right track and possibly provide some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use both of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After playing with it for awhile, I am going to answer my own question.  This is how I make it to work, so you can change it according to your needs.

Note: I use a userController instead of the siteController and please follow all the instructions in the respective extension page.

If you used the two plugins as indicated above, then what you need to do next to make it work are the followings: (this is a step by step guide)
**But the most important steps are 2c and 3, they are the glue to both plugins**

1) Have a login page that uses the OpenidSelector.  Place it at views/user/login.php

```
<?php
$this->widget('application.extensions.openidProviders.openidProviders', 
array ( 'options' => array ( 'lang' => 'en', 
//      'demo' => 'js:true',
    'cookie_expires' => 6*30,
    )));?>
```

2) Setup actions to handle the selection from the openidSelector.  I put this in the userController.

a) In main config file.

```
 'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'), //change the default login page
    ),
```

b) In userController file, add login and authenticate actions

```
array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
  'actions'=>array('login', 'authenticate'),
```

Code for action #1 actionLogin - this is to trigger the login view page.

```
public function actionLogin()
{       
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array());
}
```

c) Code for action #2 actionAuthenticate - code modified from the LOID instruction page, this is to handle when an OpenIDProvider is selected in the login page.

```
public function actionAuthenticate ()
{
   // Put the Simple usage: code on 
   // http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/loid here:

   // Code from loid Simple usage page.
   // START HERE
   $loid = Yii::app()->loid->load();
   if (!empty($_GET['openid_mode'])) {
       if ($_GET['openid_mode'] == 'cancel') {
         $err = Yii::t('core', 'Authorization cancelled');
       } else {
         try {
             echo $loid->validate() ? 'Logged in.' : 'Failed';
       } catch (Exception $e) {
             $err = Yii::t('core', $e->getMessage());
       }
   }
   if(!empty($err)) echo $err;
   } else {
       // **NOTE:Comment out this line from the loid sample page**
       // $loid->identity = "http://my.openid.identifier"; //Setting identifier
       // this openid_identifier is need after you click the openselector
       $loid->identity = $_GET['openid_identifier']; // CHANGE HERE

       $loid->required = array('namePerson/friendly', 'contact/email'); //Try to get info from openid provider
       $loid->realm     = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
       $loid->returnUrl = $loid->realm . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //getting return URL
       if (empty($err)) {
           try {
               $url = $loid->authUrl();
               $this->redirect($url);
           } catch (Exception $e) {
               $err = Yii::t('core', $e->getMessage());
           }
        }
    }
    // Code from loid Simple usage page.
    // END HERE
}
```

3)  Change the action URL to Authenticate in the openidProviders/views/main-en.php

Change

```
form action="examples/consumer/try_auth.php" method="get" id="openid_form"
```

to

```
form action="authenticate" method="get" id="openid_form"
```

That should be it.  Haven't tested failure case, only tested with google login.

Comment: Could you post an example of what else you have done in part C to make this work. I'm just not sure what needs to be done at the "print 'Logged in.';" part.  The documentation for changing other authentication mechanisms talks about modifying the the UserIdentity class. But this extension doesn't seem to work that way. Or if you don't want to post your code here. Could you write to deltaray@slugbug.org. Thanks.

Comment: Added with your sample code, I see a list of id provider, such as google, yahoo, but when I click on any of them, I am seeing 404 page not found. this is the url:http://testingenv.com/authenticate?action=verify&openid_identifier=http%3A%2F%2Fme.yahoo.com%2F any suggestion?

Comment: From your sample, I see a list of openid provider, click on any of them will bring me back to the home page. I thought should go to individual open id page, such as google, or yahoo web site. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Sorry that I have been away for awhile.  I edited the answer to include the code from LOID sample page to make it clear.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

There is [YiiAuth](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiiauth/) now, which makes use of the [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: Just been browsing for Yii authentication helpers and found this. +1 as it really helped me :)