# how to used openid in yii?

Tags: openid, yii

How to use openid selector javascript API in Yii? 
I am trying the [simpleopenidselector Yii extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/simpleopenidselector/) but I get an:

```
Error 404
Unable to resolve the request "examples/consumer/try_auth.php"
```

Please somebody guide me

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check out this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645208/openid-support-for-yii

Comment: from your error you could be testing some wrong url since I see "examples" in it and a 404 not found error, make sure you're integrating/testing the correct way

Answer (score 0):

You should config UrlManager in your config.

Could you show your config in protected/config/main.php?