# Yii openid - requested url not found?

Tags: php, yii

I tried steps in [OpenId support for Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645208/openid-support-for-yii)
But I am seeing

Not Found

The requested URL /proj1/authenticate was not found on this server.

"proj1" is my server name. My url:

http://testingenv.com/proj1.

Click on  logon, I see the login icon. But click on any of the icon, I am seeing 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. The reason is that I am not using URL rewrite. 
so I should change to

Thanks all.